# Using DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea causes window to oddly resize

Tags: winforms, aero, dwm

I have an application that uses **DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea** to draw a glass effect area at the top of my .NET Form. A strange side effect is that when you maximize and restore the window it grows taller. So if you keep maximizing/restoring it just keeps getting taller! Remove the call to **DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea** to remove that nice effect and it stops going wrong.

Any ideas?